# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am in Python 3.8 and pandas 1.1.5. I want to merge two dataframe as below but it return `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'`. How to fix it?

```
>>> df_mo
  Stock Momentum_
0  AALI         0
1  ABBA         0
>>> df_active
  Stock  Active
1  ABBA    -0.5
0  AALI     0.5
1  ABBA    -0.5
>>> pd.merge(df_mo,df_active,how='outer',on='Stock')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 74, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1063, in _get_merge_keys
    self.right = self.right._drop_labels_or_levels(right_drop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1646, in _drop_labels_or_levels
    dropped.drop(labels_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4167, in drop
    return super().drop(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3889, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3924, in _drop_axis
    result = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 309, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4036, in reindex
    return super().reindex(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4463, in reindex
    return self._reindex_axes(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3876, in _reindex_axes
    frame = frame._reindex_columns(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3921, in _reindex_columns
    return self._reindex_with_indexers(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4526, in _reindex_with_indexers
    new_data = new_data.reindex_indexer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1291, in reindex_indexer
    new_blocks = self._slice_take_blocks_ax0(indexer, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1405, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
    max_len = max(len(mgr_locs), taker.max() + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 39, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_NoValueType'
>>>
```

Comment: The example you have provided works fine. The problem is not with this: ```pd.merge(df_mo,df_active,how='outer',on='Stock')```. You have used the ```int()``` function somewhere in your code that causes this error. Mention that code in your question.

Comment: I agree with @salman, the above code its working fine